# Implementing my own algorithm to scale and rotate images in python

Tags: python, opencv, transformation

I am trying to implement an algorithm in python to scale images by a factor or rotate them by a given angle (or both at the same time). I am using opencv to handle the images and I know opencv has these functions built in, however I want to do this myself to better understand image transformations. I believe I calculate the rotation matrix correctly. However, when I try to implement the affine transformation, it does not come out correctly.

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
import math as m 
import sys

img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
angle = sys.argv[2]

#get rotation matrix
def getRMat((cx, cy), angle, scale):
    a = scale*m.cos(angle*np.pi/180)
    b = scale*(m.sin(angle*np.pi/180))
    u = (1-a)*cx-b*cy
    v = b*cx+(1-a)*cy
    return np.array([[a,b,u], [-b,a,v]]) 

#determine shape of img
h, w = img.shape[:2]
#print h, w
#determine center of image
cx, cy = (w / 2, h / 2)

#calculate rotation matrix 
#then grab sine and cosine of the matrix
mat = getRMat((cx,cy), -int(angle), 1)
print mat
cos = np.abs(mat[0,0])
sin  = np.abs(mat[0,1])

#calculate new height and width to account for rotation
newWidth = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
newHeight = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))
#print newWidth, newHeight

mat[0,2] += (newWidth / 2) - cx
mat[1,2] += (newHeight / 2) - cy

#this is how the image SHOULD look
dst = cv2.warpAffine(img, mat, (newWidth, newHeight))

cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#apply transform
#attempt at my own warp affine function...still buggy tho
def warpAff(image, matrix, (width, height)):
    dst = np.zeros((width, height, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    oldh, oldw = image.shape[:2]
    #print oldh, oldw
    #loop through old img and transform its coords
    for x in range(oldh):
        for y in range(oldw):
            #print y, x
            #transform the coordinates
            u = int(x*matrix[0,0]+y*matrix[0,1]+matrix[0,2])
            v = int(x*matrix[1,0]+y*matrix[1,1]+matrix[1,2])
            #print u, v
            #v -= width / 1.5
            if (u >= 0 and u < height) and (v >= 0 and v < width):
                dst[u,v] = image[x,y]
    return dst


dst = warpAff(img, mat, (newWidth, newHeight))

cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Image I am using for testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iheu.jpg)

Comment: When I attempted to run this code, the `dst[u, v] = image[x, y]` failed with `IndexError: index 658 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 658`. Is this only meant to work on images of a specific size or something? Without knowing what the input is supposed to be, this is not a complete or verifiable example. And I suspect it's also far from minimal. Please read [mcve] in the help.

Comment: My apologies, I am using this image for testing:  https://imgur.com/a/f0hlqwU

Comment: Please [edit] the images into the question. Comments are (intentionally) useless on Stack Overflow except for transient discussions to improve the question (very limited in size, and in formatting; not indexed by search; etc.). Also, if there's a good reason those images should work but others shouldn't, please briefly explain it (again, in the question).

Comment: The two most obvious differences are (a) you're applying the rotation counter-clockwise instead of clockwise, and (b) you're not doing any kind of interpolation or other smoothing so pixels that don't rotate exactly onto other pixels are just left at zero. Are you asking about one of those two problems, or something different?

Comment: I have now added the image to the original post. As for why this image works and not others, I am not sure why that would be the case. Futhermore, I guess my question is two parts then: how to apply the rotation clockwise and how to interpolate so i can rotate and scale up/down without black pixels.

Comment: Your basic problem is that you’re applying the matrix backward. Instead of figuring out the dst coordinates for each src pixel, figure out the src coordinates for each dst pixel. That solves your first problem (although you can also solve that by just negating the angle), and it gets you closer on your second one. But to actually get exactly there, instead of truncating each src coordinate, you need to write code that averages the coordinates left/right and up/down, so that, e.g., if you get pixel (10.25, 13) you get `.25*src[10, 13] + .75*src[11, 13]`.

Comment: But meanwhile, people usually build a 3x3 square matrix so you can just vectorize the multiplication, instead of trying to loop manually the way you are. It’s a lot simpler, but it would mean basically starting over.

Comment: Meanwhile, I'll bet your code only works on square images, which is why I got an error running it on whatever images I had lying around. There's probably a simple bug there, but if it's not important to you, I won't bother tracking it down.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide at least a rough outline of some pseudocode? I would like this code to work as universally as possible, on any image with any ratio or angle

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the rotation backward.

This means that for an angle of 20, instead of rotating 20 degrees clockwise, you rotate 20 degrees counterclockwise. That on its own would be easy to fix—just negate the angle.

But it also means that, for each destination pixel, if no source pixel exactly rotates to it, you end up with an all-black pixel. You could solve that by using any interpolation algorithm, but it's making things more complicated.

If we instead just reverse the process, and instead of calculating the destination `(u, v)` for each `(x, y)`, we calculate the source `(x, y)` for every destination `(u, v)`, that solves both problems:

```
def warpAff(image, matrix, width, height):
    dst = np.zeros((width, height, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    oldh, oldw = image.shape[:2]
    # Loop over the destination, not the source, to ensure that you cover
    # every destination pixel exactly 1 time, rather than 0-4 times.
    for u in range(width):
        for v in range(height):
            x = u*matrix[0,0]+v*matrix[0,1]+matrix[0,2]
            y = u*matrix[1,0]+v*matrix[1,1]+matrix[1,2]
            intx, inty = int(x), int(y)
            # We could interpolate here by using something like this linear
            # interpolation matrix, but let's keep it simple and not do that.
            # fracx, fracy = x%1, y%1
            # interp = np.array([[fracx*fracy, (1-fracx)*fracy],
            #                    [fracx*(1-fracy), (1-fracx)*(1-fracy)]])
            if 0 < x < oldw and 0 < y < oldh:
                dst[u, v] = image[intx, inty]
    return dst
```

Now the only remaining problem is that you *didn't* apply the shift backward, so we end up shifting the image in the wrong direction when we turn everything else around. That's trivial to fix:

```
mat[0,2] += cx - (newWidth / 2)
mat[1,2] += cy - (newHeight / 2)
```

---

You do have one more problem: your code (and this updated code) only works for square images. You're getting height and width backward multiple times, and they almost all cancel out, but apparently one of them doesn't. In general, you're treating your arrays as `(width, height)` rather than `(height, width)`, but you end up comparing to (original version) or looping over (new version) `(height, width)`. So, if height and width are different, you end up trying to write past the end of the array.

Trying to find all of these and fix them is probably as much work as just starting over and doing it consistently everywhere from the start:

```
mat = getRMat(cx, cy, int(angle), 1)
cos = np.abs(mat[0,0])
sin  = np.abs(mat[0,1])
newWidth = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
newHeight = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))
mat[0,2] += cx - (newWidth / 2)
mat[1,2] += cy - (newHeight / 2)

def warpAff2(image, matrix, width, height):
    dst = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    oldh, oldw = image.shape[:2]
    for u in range(width):
        for v in range(height):
            x = u*matrix[0,0]+v*matrix[0,1]+matrix[0,2]
            y = u*matrix[1,0]+v*matrix[1,1]+matrix[1,2]
            intx, inty = int(x), int(y)
            if 0 < intx < oldw and 0 < inty < oldh:
                pix = image[inty, intx]
                dst[v, u] = pix
    return dst

dst = warpAff2(img, mat, newWidth, newHeight)
```

---

It's worth noting that there are much simpler (and more efficient) ways to implement this. If you build a 3x3 square matrix, you can vectorize the multiplication. Also, you can create the matrix more simply by just multiplying a shift matrix @ a rotation matrix @ an unshift matrix instead of manually fixing things up after the fact. But hopefully this version, since it's as close as possible to your original, should be easiest to understand.

Comment: Wow this is amazing and super comprehensive. I really appreciate it! One last question, there seems to be some slight offset in the output image (it is not perfectly framed within the window); is there a reason for this?

Comment: @LoganCrocker Well, you're truncating floats to int, which is going to make everything off by 0-1 pixels. And you have at least two of those truncates, so they can add up… Does the error look like more than 2 pixels, or less?

Comment: It's considerable. Maybe 20-30% of the image goes up toward the top left corner and out of view. Also, things get a bit wonky when passing large angles into the function. But I am by no means asking you to do all of this for me, you have already been very helpful and I've learned a lot! Thank you

Comment: @LoganCrocker Did you do the `mat[0, 2]` fix, to reverse the direction of the shift?

Comment: Yes I did. I simply used the code you provided. Are you not getting the same problem?

Comment: @LoganCrocker I'm definitely seeing an error of a few pixels in the shift—possibly more than 2 pixels, but nowhere near 20-30%. For example, with your test image, the rightmost non-black pixel is at 163/163 in the cv2 version, 159/162 in the manual version.

Comment: Very strange, @abarnert here is a link to an example.  [https://imgur.com/a/6VoQCyw] I'll inspect the code and see if I can figure it out.